# Android apk api url http to https migration

Tags: android, api, web-services, ssl

I am planning to enable SSL in my web application. Here i have doubt that currently in my application's android app api path is

```
 String URL = "http://IP-Address/JavaRESTfullWS/DemoService/login";
```

After enabling SSL url should change to

```
 String URL = "https://IP-Address/JavaRESTfullWS/DemoService/login";
```

Or Still no changes required ?

Comment: try it and see if it works?

Comment: @njzk2 it is live. Need exact solution

Comment: I don't understand. If you want to connect to your https server, you need an https url.